# Intercept resource binding with a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I have my localized text resources in a separate project in the solution, AppResources. This allows a paid translator to work on resource translations without having the entire application source code.

In my Window, I have the namespace declared:

```
xmlns:viewProperties="clr-namespace:AppResources.Properties;assembly=AppResources"
```

And example control:

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
  Margin="3" 
  Text="{x:Static viewProperties:Resources.TextBlockUserName}" />
```

This is all working properly. I change the culture, the appropriate resource is used. I'm trying to maintain the benefit that the keys in viewProperties:Resources are available through autocomplete in the XAML, so we know it's there.

I am hoping to add some kind of converter here to intercept the resource string value and either do one of 2 things:

- Pass through the acquired resource string value (e.g. culture is Japanese, send that localize text through)
- Display the name of the resource key that is being requested from the control

The reason for this is to provide an application option to go into "translation mode" and instead of displaying the translated resource text like OK, Cancel, Save, etc. the application would display the key names (e.g. Button_OK, Button_Cancel, File_Save or whatever the key names were). This is handy to know the context of what the translator is trying to understand.

Anyway, the converter I'm trying to use works, but is not ideal:

```
public class TranslationKeyInterceptor : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Can do this, but this is horrible
        string resourceName = value.ToString().Replace("x:Static viewProperties:Resources.", string.Empty);

        string resourceString = string.Empty;
        if (AppOptions.DisplayLanguageKeys)
        {
            resourceString = resourceName;
        }
        else
        {
            resourceString = AppResources.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
        }

        return resourceString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The value it is getting is the entire path coming from the XAML, so I can't parse out just the key name.

Also the XAML becomes a little messier because I need to

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
  Margin="3" 
  Text="{x:Static viewProperties:Resources.TextBlockUserName, 
  Converter={StaticResource Converter_Translate}}" />
```

Where

```
    <wpfTools:TranslationKeyInterceptor x:Key="Converter_Translate"/>
```

is declared in my Window's Resources.

So my question is either:

- Can I pass into the converter the actual string property that exists in AppResources.Properties.Resources somehow to maintain autocomplete in the XAML and use that name to perform my option's logic?
- What is the best way to accomplish this "text interception" and either let the resource text through or capture who is asking for in in XAML and instead return the requested key's name?

Comment: The easy way would be to autogenerate a culture with the resource values identical to the names. You would also create a MarkupExtension, but I'm not sure how to keep the compile time check on the ResourceKey.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment: just make a new culture where the value for each key is in fact the key's name. Then when you're in "translation" mode, you just use that culture instead of an actual human culture. It's a good question, but I think you're just overthinking the problem.

Comment: OK, good suggestion. I'm not opposed to pursuing that kind of solution. Any ideas on how to do this? I already have my list of keys in each of the existing languages. Also I'm using ResXManager which doesn't seem to let you create a made-up language. It would be a pain to add a new key in there and then copy and paste them in the Resources.en-Trnl (or whatever) translation resx.